# Run Python model from Power BI on new data samples entered by the user in Power BI

Tags: python, powerbi

The question is in regards to Power BI and It would great if I can get your advice on the best approach if possible and any alternatives if its not possible.

Basically I have a model that I developed in Python and imported in Power BI, then ran it on a dataset and got the estimated target variable. I am visualizing the output in Power BI with a dashboard etc.
What I want to do is use Power BI to provide estimates for new data samples entered manually by the user in the same Power BI dashboard. So basically using Power BI as an interactive estimating tool based on the Python model loaded in Power BI. At the moment the model only shows the range the Python model is built on, as an example the data model only has limited number of values for each feature however using the python script I can predict models of any feature value in theory but Power BI does not let me go above the values entered in the original model.

I hope this makes sense and happy to explain any points that are not clear.

I look forward to hearing from you.

Regards

Comment: Are you talking large datasets entered by users?

Comment: No, just a single sample each time. Som the idea is to get an estimation for the target variable.

Comment: One option would be power apps integration with direct query table. Basically users would be able to enter new values in power app visual and write it back to the back end db. Another option would be a visual with write back option. Both of these solutions would write data to the database backend.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Can I just clarify the purpose of writing to the dB? The idea is to get an estimation for the target variable which means I need to find a way to call the model which is available in the python script inside Power Bi to predict the output, that is the target variable.